# P2 Autoupdate from web repository

Tags: eclipse, repository, eclipse-rcp, p2

I have some problems with P2's autoupdate, when I do locally, from a local repository all work fine and I can do my autoupdates at restart but when I try to update from a web repo I have these errors:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Install download0".
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
```

Really, I don't understand what the difference is.
In my ApplicationWindowWorkbenchAdvisor I have this post window open method:

```
private static final String JUSTUPDATED = "justUpdated";

public void postWindowOpen() {
    final IProvisioningAgent agent = (IProvisioningAgent) ServiceHelper
            .getService(Activator.bundleContext,
                    IProvisioningAgent.SERVICE_NAME);
    if (agent == null) {
        LogHelper
                .log(new Status(IStatus.ERROR, Activator.PLUGIN_ID,
                        "No provisioning agent found.  This application is not set up for updates."));
    }
    final IPreferenceStore prefStore = Activator.getDefault()
            .getPreferenceStore();
    if (prefStore.getBoolean(JUSTUPDATED)) {
        prefStore.setValue(JUSTUPDATED, false);
        return;
    }

    IRunnableWithProgress runnable = new IRunnableWithProgress() {
        public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor)
                throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
            IStatus updateStatus = P2Util.checkForUpdates(agent, monitor);
            if (updateStatus.getCode() == UpdateOperation.STATUS_NOTHING_TO_UPDATE) {
                PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay()
                        .asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                MessageDialog.openInformation(null,
                                        "Updates", "No updates were found");
                            }
                        });
            } else if (updateStatus.getSeverity() != IStatus.ERROR) {
                prefStore.setValue(JUSTUPDATED, true);
                PlatformUI.getWorkbench().restart();
            } else {
                LogHelper.log(updateStatus);
            }
        }
    };
    try {
        new ProgressMonitorDialog(null).run(true, true, runnable);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }

}
```

And in my P2Util this:

```
    public static IStatus checkForUpdates(IProvisioningAgent agent,
        IProgressMonitor monitor) {
    ProvisioningSession session = new ProvisioningSession(agent);
    UpdateOperation operation = new UpdateOperation(session);
    SubMonitor sub = SubMonitor.convert(monitor,
            "Checking for application updates...", 200);
    IStatus status = operation.resolveModal(sub.newChild(100));
    if (status.getCode() == UpdateOperation.STATUS_NOTHING_TO_UPDATE) {
        return status;
    }
    if (status.getSeverity() == IStatus.CANCEL)
        throw new OperationCanceledException();

    if (status.getSeverity() != IStatus.ERROR) {
        ProvisioningJob job = operation.getProvisioningJob(null);
        status = job.runModal(sub.newChild(100));
        if (status.getSeverity() == IStatus.CANCEL)
            throw new OperationCanceledException();
    } 
    return status;
}
```

In my PreferenceInitializer this:

```
node.putBoolean(PreferenceConstants.PREF_AUTO_UPDATE_ENABLED, true);
node.putBoolean(PreferenceConstants.PREF_AUTO_UPDATE_SCHEDULE, true);
node.putBoolean(PreferenceConstants.PREF_DOWNLOAD_ONLY, true);
```

I repeat myself: from local repo I can perform autoupdates but from web repo I can't.
Thank for reading.

Answer (score 4):

the problematic code is

```
new ProgressMonitorDialog(null).run(true, true, runnable);
```

this is called outside the ui-thread which throws the error...you have to wrap this also in a asyncExec Call

Comment: yes, I found that "solution" on internet but always gives me that error. as you said the problem is the new ProgressMonitor. if you introduce instead of that the NullProgressMonitor all works fine:  IStatus updateStatus = P2Util.checkForUpdates(agent, new NullProgressMonitor()); Thanks :)